# Why are my html tags showing when I view this file in browser?

Tags: html

Title pretty much says it all. I think it is formatted correctly, but for some reason I still see the tags when opened with a browser. Sorry about the wall of code, I'm pretty sure the problem is very simple but it is just easiest for me to copy and paste the whole thing right now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1038.36">
  <style type="text/css">
    p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px Helvetica}
    p.p2 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px Helvetica; min-height: 14.0px}
    span.Apple-tab-span {white-space:pre}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1">&lt;html xmlns="http://www.assignment9.com/xhtml"&gt;</p>
<p class="p1">&lt;head&gt; &lt;title&gt;James&lt;/title&gt; &lt;/head&gt;</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1">&lt;body style="background-color : black; color : white"&gt;</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span>&lt;h1&gt;Musical background&lt;/h1&gt;</p>
<p class="p1">&lt;p&gt;James has had a rich musical background.<span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>He started playing the upright bass at 10 years old.<span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>From there he moved to the electric bass at 13 and guitar at 15.<span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>Guitar is his true love and calling.<span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>James has been self taught on guitar for 8 years and is now gigging fairly often in the hartford area. &lt;/p&gt;</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span>&lt;h2&gt;James' Favorite Musical Groups&lt;/h2&gt;</p>
<p class="p1">&lt;p&gt;With all the genre's of music out there, James has been influenced by bands and artists from several genre's including, The Eagles, Van Halen, Brad Paisley, Europe, Joe Bonamassa.<span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>&lt;/p&gt;</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1">&lt;img src="IMG_0123" alt="PRS Santana SE/&gt;</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span>&lt;h3&gt;Musical Instruments&lt;/h3&gt;</p>
<p class="p1">&lt;p&gt;James currently 4 guitars and he loves each and everyone one of them.<span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>His first guitar was a Fender Stratocaster.<span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>It served as his only electric guitar until earlier this year when he purchased a PRS Santana SE.<span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>This is now his primary electric guitar.<span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>For acoustic guitars, has a Takemine G Series acoustic electric guitar and a Breedlove 514CE acoustic electric guitar.<span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>He frequently is seen giggling with both guitars&lt;/p&gt;</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1">&lt;/body&gt;</p>
<p class="p1">&lt;/html&gt;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `&lt;p&gt;` these cause the characters to be taken literally instead of interpreted as HTML tags, your HTML must be getting mangled somewhere

Comment: Also, genres not genre's. James currently **has**...

Comment: You are probably trying to write html in a WYSIWYG html editor which doesn't really work unless you have a 'source' button

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you use Cocoa HTML writer but pasted HTML into the Visual (WYSIWYG) editor. The problem with this is that it encodes all of your tags with the html encoded equivalent (e.g. &gt;) 
If this software has an HTML/source view try pasting your content into there and then saving.

If not paste the content into a normal text editor that does not do html formatting and then save the file with an .html extension.

If you are not sure how to extract the original HTML code remove the <p> tags and then copy the text into a site like: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/decode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the content in your HTML is HTML Entities. `&lt;` is the same as a literal < and `&gt;` is the same as > so, it IS formatting your html correctly, but your content just looks like HTML.

Here is a link on HTML Entities: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp